# Can't download Godapp

Tags: games

Whenever I click on the link to download Godapp, the link just takes me to a 403 page. I was wondering how to fix this as this did not happen when I downloaded Godapp the last time I did this.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Godapp6?lang=en

Comment: https://godapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

GODAPP is a website that provides statistics and evaluation of dapps applications.GODAPP provides all the information and analysis about existing dapps! Based on eos, eth, singer, nebula chain, etc., you can find successful and useful decentralized games with just a finger touch.Godapp can't download.You can go to Twitter to find out about the Twitter account Godapp@Godapp6.

Answer (score 0):

GoDapp is a DAPP store,you can download the dapp game above.You can check out the novice guide on the website.Try again[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlvjj.jpg)